# How to merge 2 executables in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, merge

How can one merge 2 executables? I am allowing the user to compile their own program within mine. I want them to as well have an option to merge their compiled program with a program that they have.

How can such be possible in C#? I have seen it done before in C++.

Comment: Do you want a "pseudo-compiled" scripting language (like with node-webkit)? Typically the script is concatenated onto the binary and the program reads it.

Comment: Well. Sorry if I am a bit confused by what you mean. But I want the user to be able to merge their C# program (which I compiled for them), with another application. I am not sure how node-webkit would go along with this.

Comment: Oh you mean a file binder; You'll need an "stub" that unpacks the compiled code and the other application somewhere. Then run both programs.

Comment: Lookup ILMerge, merging a DLL an exe is easy. Merging two exe's isn't really practical as you need one Main()